# Why using 2 different timers via grand-central-dispatch doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I used before one timer in my app for periodically launched task (token refresh actually). I found code example on stackoverflow and it worked for me.

This is the code example definition (above implementation header):

```
dispatch_source_t CreateDispatchTimer(double interval, dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block)
{
    dispatch_source_t timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    if (timer)
    {
        dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10);
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer, block);
        dispatch_resume(timer);
    }
    return timer;
}
```

this is the variables definitions:

```
dispatch_source_t _timer;
static double SECONDS_TO_FIRE = 60.000f;
```

and then there is a method e.g. `startTimer` where I launched this timer:

```
- (void)startTimer {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    _timer = CreateDispatchTimer(SECONDS_TO_FIRE, queue, ^{

        // NSLog(@"timer is fired");
        // do smth I need

        }
    });
}
```

So this code worked for me very well.

Now I need another (second) timer for separate task that should be fired in own time interval.

So I copied code above in separate class, set up another time interval.
Faced that if I use the same name for `dispatch_source_t` - like `CreateDispatchTimer` above, application won't be compiled!

So for second timer in separate class I changed the `dispatch_source_t` name to another, like `CreateTimerDispatch`. So app was compiled successfully.

But, the problem is - only second timer works now! The first time is not fired at all!

How to fix this? Can now understand why only last timer is fired.

Comment: Looks like it change the `timer` name for second dispatch timer too - then in works. Testing now.

Comment: is there a (good) reason you aren't using `NSTimer` ?

Comment: it didn't work for me, thus I started using GCD as I found working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason - except renaming `dispatch_source_t CreateDispatchTimer` block with different name for these 2 timers,
I needed to rename `timer` variable for second timer too.

I caught that the first timer was completely overwritten by second timer (as it was created later). Thus the first timer didn't fire at all.

So the working code example for second timer is following:

```
dispatch_source_t CreateLocationTimerDispatch(double interval, dispatch_queue_t queue, dispatch_block_t block) {
    dispatch_source_t timerForLocationRefresh = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    if (timerForLocationRefresh) {
        dispatch_source_set_timer(timerForLocationRefresh, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval * NSEC_PER_SEC), interval * NSEC_PER_SEC, (1ull * NSEC_PER_SEC) / 10);
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerForLocationRefresh, block);
        dispatch_resume(timerForLocationRefresh);
    }
    return timerForLocationRefresh;
}
```

variable:

```
dispatch_source_t _timerForLocationRefresh;
static double SECONDS_TO_FIRE = 1800.f; // time interval lengh in seconds 1800
```

calling:

```
- (void)startTimer {
    // second timer
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    _timerForLocationRefresh = CreateLocationTimerDispatch(SECONDS_TO_FIRE, queue, ^{

        // do smth
    });
}
```

Summary:

- `CreateDispatchTimer` block for second timer needed to be renamed, e.g. > `CreateLocationTimerDispatch`
- `timer` variable for second timer needed to be renamed too, e.g. > `timerForLocationRefresh`